# Can the product of $n$ positive integers, where $n \gt 5$ in A.P. be a palindrome?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, palindrome

Reading the question [can the product of four positive integers in A.P. be a square?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3196953/can-the-product-of-four-positive-integers-in-a-p-be-a-square/3197978#3197978), also made me question whether the product of $n$ positive integers, where $n \gt 5$ in arithmetic progression be a palindrome?

Me and user [Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82961/peter) tried to find solutions for various $n$ in PARI/GP, and found that there were no solutions for a large range of numbers we tested when $n \gt 5$.

This led to the following questions:

> ($1$)   Can the product of $n$ positive integers, where $n \gt 5$ in A.P. be a palindrome?
>
> ($2$) If yes then for what value of $n$ is there no solution?

Comment: There are slight restrictions that accelerate the search : The difference $d$ cannot be coprime to $10$ , and if it is congruent to $2,4,6$ or $8$ modulo $10$, the only possible palindrome is $5\cdots 5$

Comment: A general lower bound for the value of the product is $$(n-1)!\cdot 2^{n-1}$$ which makes it unlikely, that a solution for large $n$ exists.